# ¿Como realizar un bloqueo en nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, visual-studio

Hola buenas estoy realizando un ejercicio sobre una cuenta bancaria es facilito ya que estoy empezando y me gustaria saber como se realiza el bloqueo para que si al restar el saldo es negativo saque el mensaje de Saldo negativo en vez restar.
Este es el codigo:

```js
let saldo = 200;
setTimeout(ComprobarSaldo1, 1000);
ComprobarSaldo2(); 

function ComprobarSaldo1(){
    if (saldo - 150 > 0){
        saldo -= 150;
        console.log(saldo)
    }else{
        console.log("Saldo Negativo");
    }
}

function ComprobarSaldo2(){
    if(saldo - 175 > 0){
        setTimeout(() => {
            saldo -= 175;
            console.log(saldo)
        }, 2000);
    }else{ console.log("Saldo Negativo");}
}

// Parte del bloqueo que no deje restar al ser negativa
```

Como veis es simple son dos funciones y ambas restan pero no consigo realizar la parte en el que como al salir de la 1 función el saldo es 50 que  bloquee la segunda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las operaciones en las que dos hilos acceden a un mismo recurso deben ser atómicas: o se realizan de una sola vez (sin interrupciones), o no se hacen. Por tanto, el `setTimeout` dentro `ComprobarSaldo2` no debería estar ahí: debes quitarlo o hacer la comprobación dentro del mismo:

```js
let saldo = 200;
setTimeout(ComprobarSaldo1, 1000);
ComprobarSaldo2(); 

function ComprobarSaldo1(){
    if (saldo - 150 > 0){
        saldo -= 150;
        console.log(saldo)
    }else{
        console.log("Saldo Negativo");
    }
}

function ComprobarSaldo2(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(saldo - 175 > 0){
      saldo -= 175;
      console.log(saldo)
    }else{ console.log("Saldo Negativo");}
  }, 2000);
    
}

// Parte del bloqueo que no deje restar al ser negativa
```